# Large image with Facebook share_open_graph, possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

I have a problem with Facebook API. I want to share some information (url, image, description) on facebook from a website. But I want to see a large image in the preview dialog. I use `share_open_graph`:

```
FB.ui({
method: 'share_open_graph',
action_type: 'share',
action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object : {
       'og:url': 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs',
       'og:title': 'Facebook Developer Docs',
       'og:description': 'Learn more about our Facebook products through Developer docs. Explore Facebook documentation for AR/VR, Business, Chat, Games, Machine Learning, Monetization, Open Source & Social.',
       'og:image': 'https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/lWB96Z8sFtt.png',
       'og:image:width': '1200', 
       'og:image:height': '630',
       'og:image:type': 'image/jpeg'
    }
})
},function(response) {});
```

[image]

How can I change it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images says you will only get square images when you share as an Open Graph story, if your app is a Game app; but I think that might be the case for other types of app as well now. Plus, you don’t seem to have an _actual_ OG story here, but are rather using this just as a workaround to be able to still specify those additional parameters at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'share' method instead of 'share_open_graph', like this:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/